# Trying to access FirstData's WSDL via API on Localhost w/ PHP

Tags: php, api, soap, curl, wsdl

First of all, let me say that I'm relatively new to SOAP/WSDL/API, so this post is going to be a bit verbose, because I have no clue whats's going on. I've been googling things for the last few hours with no luck. I'm hoping someone here can point me in the right direction so I can move on.

I'm trying to utilize FirstData's API to make a PHP payment script. I'm having issues accessing their [WSDL](https://ws.firstdataglobalgateway.com/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl) via their API using PHP.  My curl is (based on their [documentation](https://www.firstdata.com/downloads/marketing-merchant/FDGG-Web-Service-API-v4.5.pdf)):

```
$wsdl = "https://ws.merchanttest.firstdataglobalgateway.com/fdggwsapi/services/order.wsdl";

$userid = "WSxxxxxxxxxxx._.1";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$pemlocation = realpath("WSxxxxxxxxxx._.1.pem");
$kslocation = realpath("WSxxxxxxxxxx._.1.key");
$keyname = "ckp_xxxxxxxx";

$transactiontype = "sale";
$creditcardnumber = "4111111111111111";
$cardexpirationmonth = "10";
$cardexpirationyear = "12";
$chargetotal = "1";

$body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
$body .= "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-    ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
$body .= "<SOAP-ENV:Header />";
$body .= "<SOAP-ENV:Body>";
$body .= "<fdggwsapi:FDGGWSApiOrderRequest xmlns:fdggwsapi= \"http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/fdggwsapi\">";
$body .= "<v1:Transaction xmlns:v1= \"http://secure.linkpt.net/fdggwsapi/schemas_us/v1\">";
$body .= "<v1:CreditCardTxType>";
$body .= "<v1:Type>";
$body .= $transactiontype;
$body .= "</v1:Type>";
$body .= "</v1:CreditCardTxType>";
$body .= "<v1:CreditCardData>";
$body .= "<v1:CardNumber>";
$body .= $creditcardnumber;
$body .= "</v1:CardNumber>";
$body .= "<v1:ExpMonth>";
$body .= $cardexpirationmonth;
$body .= "</v1:ExpMonth>";
$body .= "<v1:ExpYear>";
$body .= $cardexpirationyear;
$body .= "</v1:ExpYear>";
$body .= "</v1:CreditCardData>";
$body .= "<v1:Payment>";
$body .= "<v1:ChargeTotal>";
$body .= $chargetotal;
$body .= "</v1:ChargeTotal>";
$body .= "</v1:Payment>";
$body .= "</v1:Transaction>";
$body .= "</fdggwsapi:FDGGWSApiOrderRequest>";
$body .= "</SOAP-ENV:Body>";
$body .= "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";

$ch = curl_init($wsdl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$userid:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $pemlocation);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $kslocation);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, $keyname);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

Which returns a `HTTP Status 401 - type: Status report | description: This request requires HTTP authentication (). | JBossWeb/2.0.0.GA`. According to their documentation `OpenSSL`, a `SSL certificate` and `TCP Port 1129` are required. Since I was getting nothing returned, I assumed it was because my OpenSSL isn't set up on my XAMPP. If this makes no sense(?) Skip the next bit.

I tried to set up my SSL in apache under XAMPP. `xampp\apache\makecert` yields :

```
Unable to load config info from ./bin/openssl.cnf
Error opening Private Key privkey.pem
6264:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:.\crypto\bio\bass_file.c:356:fopen('privkey.pem','rb')
6264:error:20064002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:.\crypto\bio\file.c:358:unable to load Private Key
Loading 'screen' into random state - done
server.csr: No such file or directory
Could Not Find c:\xampp\apache\.rnd
Could Not Find c:\xampp\apache\prikey.pem
Could Not Find c:\xampp\apache\server.csr
The system cannot find the file specified.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

My openssl.cnf is located @ `c:\xampp\php\extras\openssl\openssl.cnf`. I did a `openssl req -new -key digitss.key -out digitss.csr -config "c:\xampp\php\extras\openssl\openssl.cnf"` which made worked, but in the end did nothing. I'm unsure how to get the SSL running.

In any event, if anyone could shine some light on my issue, I would be much obliged. I don't know if it's my PHP, the `$body` var, or the fact that I'm trying access the WSDL without SSL (or a combination of all 3). I've seen a few variations of the code I used, so I'm thinking it is right. I have a trial account for FirstData set up, as well as the .pem and .key files that I can send anyone if they want to help me investigate this. I'm at a total loss!

Thanks in advance,

Tre

Comment: tr3online were you able to solve this problem? If yes, can you please post your solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your mixing up the First Data APIs.

There are 2 First Data APIs:

- First Data Global Gateway API 2
- First Data Global Gateway Web Service API

The Web Service API is send over port 443, the legacy API is send over port 1129.

You want to use port 443 for the code you have listed above in your curl request.

Comment: I have the same issue, but i can't get solution. Are you adding the port by curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443); way ???